# Constraints breaking for iPhone 6+ with dynamically sizing cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a UITableViewCell setup like below:

[image]

An image with the date, a divider line (UIView) and a text field. Constraints are set like so:

Image: pin top top, trailing and leading edges, aspect ratio enabled.

Date: pin to top (image), leading, fixed height and width

Divider: pin to top (date), trailing, leading, fixed height

Text: pin to top (divider), bottom, trailing, leading, fixed height

I want the cells to dynamically change size depending on the size of the content so in my UITableViewController I have:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 254
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

I have tested it for iPhone4, iPhone5 and iPhone6. It all works fine. However for iPhone6+ I get the error in the console: 
*Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.*

It looks fine in the simulator though. What could I be doing wrong here? If the cells and views size up correctly for the other phone sizes then why would it break for the 6+?

Any pointers on this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are aware of how auto layout constraints work. Auto lay out constraints are nothing more than the mathmetical expressions and they get evaluated every time your view gets laid out.

In your case, your constraints says:
height of the image after resizing image maintaining aspect ratio + date picker height(fixed)+devider height(fixed)+textfield height+distance from textfield to bottom layout guide(fixed) = row height ;

now this will obviosuly break auto layout constraint as you have specified fixed a distance from bottom layout to text field.

what is happenning in here is, no matter whatever is the size of row, ios will try to maintain the fixed distance between textfield bottom and the rows bottom. This will cause chain of constraints break.

This constraint is completely un necessary. As you have already specified minal required constraints for text field by giving pin to top (divider), trailing, leading, fixed height :)

Though removing constraint will solve the constraint breaking issue, but there are still issues with your design buddy.

Happy coding :)

Comment: The bottom constraint it actually needed for the UITableViewAutomaticDimension to work. I see what you mean about the constraints breaking though. I managed to fix it by removing the fixed height from the text field and that allows the flexibility for it all to fit. What are the issues with the design?

Comment: ohhhh sorry I completely ignored UITableViewAutomaticDimension, my bad. In the absence of UITableViewAutomaticDimension, removing bottom constraint as i mentioned will lead to some other UI issues is what i meant :) as you have fixed width constraints on other components as well :) Good that you resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the priority of one of the constraints that determines the height to 999 instead of 1000. The last-to-bottom one for example. It usually removes the problem of the constraint breaking while the cell is figuring out it's height and will look the same.